# Navigation Components prevent orientation change for some fragments

Tags: android, orientation

I'm using the Navigation Components and want to not allow rotations on some of the fragments. Ie: I have a nav bar with three fragments A (home), B, and C and want B and C to be able to go into landscape but not A.

I don't want this solution because it affects the whole app

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped rotation in some fragments using

onResume() - to lock the orientation in portrait

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

onStop() - to remove the portrait lock

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
```